# possible locking issue with a Talend job

Tags: etl, talend

I'm parsing data from one table and writing it back to another one. Input are characteristics, written as text. Output is a boolean field that needs to be updated. For example a characteristic would be "has 4 wheel drive" and I want to set a boolean has_4weeldrive to true.

I'm going through all the characteristics that belong to a car and set it to true if found, else to null. The filter after the tmap_1 filters the rows for which the attribute is true, and then updates that in a table. I want to do that for all different characteristics (around 10).

If I do it for one characteristic the job runs fine, as soon as I have more than 1 it only loads 1 record and waits indefinitely. I can of course make 10 jobs and it will run, but I need to touch all the characteristics 10 times, that doesn't feel right. Is this a locking issue? Is there a better way to do this? Target and source db is Postgresql if that makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: Are you using shared connections? That could cause problems like this. Also make sure you're committing after each update, that could solve the problem. Talend uses 1 thread for execution (except the enterprise version) but having multiple shared outputs could cause problems.

Comment: setting the commit to 1 instead of the default 10000 solved the issue. Would you care to write it down as an answer so that I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared connections could cause problems like this. 
Also make sure you're committing after each update. Talend use 1 thread for execution (except the enterprise version) so multiple shared outputs could cause problems.

Setting the commit to 1 should eliminate the problem.